# Are there any resources for understanding Ethereum2.0?

Tags: serenity

I am entering Ethereum from Bitcoin world. And I have been reading [Ethereum Developers Docs](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/) a while, but I still find it difficult to understand how Ethereum2.0 works. Something like [this one](https://eth2book.info/bellatrix/) maybe beneficial, but many chapters of it hasn't yet finished. So any other useful resources to recommend?

Comment: Your question is too broad. There isn't an Ethereum 2.0 the 2.0 was dropped because people were doing an incorrect interpretation. It is an evolutionary path where different technologies are incorporated to the existing Ethereum blockchain. So in order to understand you can start by reading for example Mastering Ethereum. If there's something more specific you don't understand try asking here or on https://ethresear.ch/.

Comment: @Ismael Actially, I've finished reading Mastering Ethereum. But it seems that this book doesn't cover how PoS, sharding, etc. works.

Comment: There's the book "Proof of Stake" by Vitalik Buterin with some of the papers that were used as base. I haven't seen a book about the whole thing, perhaps Ben Edingtons's book should be the closest. If you like to read specs you can check the repo https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs.